# Proofs of $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $\#P\subseteq FP^{PP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

$P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $\#P\subseteq FP^{PP}$ are known and usually handwaived as exercises. I could not find proofs of these two results.

What is a rigorous proof for $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $\#P\subseteq FP^{PP}$?

How is having an oracle to $\#P$ at most as powerful as having an oracle to $PP$?

Answer (score 6):

This is not the full proof but the complete idea:

Let Turing machine $M$, define  $L_M$  be the language defined as  $L_M = \{ ((x, y) \in \Sigma^*\times \mathbb{N}  ~|~ \#\text{accepting path of } {M}(x) > y \} $

Then prove that $L_M\in PP$.

Now use the binary search technique to compute the function g(x) in $\#P$ using $L_M$.

And other way around its easy by using $\#P$ function TM you can always answer whether no. of accepting paths are more $\frac{1}{2}$ or not.

Let $L\in P^{\#p}$, then there is a deterministic oracle Turing machine $M'$ that runs polynomial time, and a function $g\in \#p$
such that  $L= M'^{g}$. Let $M$ be a poly time Turing machine that uses at most $poly(n)$ non-deterministic steps such that $g(x)=\# acceptig pathof M"(x)$.   Use the standard binary search technique to show that  $g(x)$ can be computed  using $O(n)$ many queries to the language $L_M$.

$x$, oracle access to $L_M$ and output $g(x)$.

1. Initialize $p=|x|$, $y=2^p$.
2. Repeat steps 3 & 4 until $p\ge 0$
3. Query $(x,y)$ to the oracle;  If YES, then set $y=y+2^{p+1}$;

   Else

   break .
4. Set $p=p-1$

Now we know the range for g which is $2^{p-1}<g<2^{p}$
$use binary search technique in this range and since there can be exponential terms hence binary search technique will take O(|x|) time.

Clearly, the algorithm  above runs in time ${\sf poly}(n)$, and hence computing $g$ can be done in $poly$ with oracle access to $L_M\in PP$.

Comment: "Now use the binary search technique to compute the function g(x)" How?

Comment: Take an example, let say the number of accepting paths in Turing machine in x. We want to find this x using our language L_m which is in PP. We know that the total number of paths in the T.M.  take y=0 in L_m and run PP machine for L_m if answer is Yes than set y= $(2^{|\Sigma|})/2$ if answer is No than x=0. Repeat this steps like you would do in binary search by setting value of y each iteration will give you interval in which x lies.

Comment: @Bitty I still do not understand. Could you please elaborate completely in your main post?

Comment: @turbo I have added the algorithm and correctnessand analysis is easy.

Comment: Actually I do not know which one you are proving? are you showing $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$?

Comment: I also donot get the standard binary search technique.

Comment: yes I proved $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$. I wrote the binary search algorithm in answer.

Comment: what is a k-restricted turing machine (this seems essential for proof).

Comment: Yeah hi I am sorry I wrote k-restrcted TM its just poly time TM. I proved this statement in FPT complexity thats why by mistake I wrote k-restricted but what problem are you facing?

Comment: why is it $g(x,k)$ what does $k$ mean? can you rewrite without typos clearly? I also do not understand your steps $3$ and $4$ and you are using same $x$ through out the loop (and so if accepting path count $> 2^p$ then it will also be $>2^{p-1}$ and so $b$ is always of form $0000\dots001111\dots11$.

Comment: I updated algorithm again hopes it will help now.

Comment: ok this proves both $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $\#P\subseteq FP^{PP}$ correct? why do we need for $b_p$ and how do we 'use binary search technique in this range'? Actually I still do not get your loop (you say repeat until $p\geq0$ but you change $p$ nowhere in loop).

Comment: p changes in line 4. You know the range then u can again query to PP oracle (x,y) where y= $(2^p-2{p-1})/2$ if yes then go in the next half otherwise previous half.

Comment: What is need for $b_p$?

Comment: yes now we dont need $b_p$ thanks for the correction.

Comment: actually can you mathematically prove what you are claiming? Your writing is very difficult to follow.

Comment: I have proved $P^{\#P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and which part of proof you did not understand?

Comment: The proof is unclear. Make it rigorous.